# How to switch between test and production databases with Entity Framework 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I've got separate test and production databases for my ASP.NET MVC 4 application.  Using Entity Framework 5, how can I have Entity Framework switch between these two databases programmatically?  The application knows which database should be used at which time, so I just need for the application to be able to change Entity Framework so that it utilizes the correct database at the correct time.

Anyone know how to accomplish this and/or have a good example available?

---

EDIT: due to how my app is arranged, I am going to need to utlize GvM's answer.  The last remaining thing, however, is that I don't know how to send an argument to the base class.  Here is what I mean:

```
public class YourContext : DbContext {

    public YourContext() : base("yourNameOrConnectionString")
    {
    }

}
```

The problem is that this code does not work:

```
string dbConnectionString = "MyDBTest";

using (var db = new YourContext(dbConnectionString))
{
    //code to use the db
}
```

How does one send an argument to a base class, in this case YourContext() : base()

Answer (score 20):

Use the config transforms. That's what they're there for. Admittedly, though, the config transforms are a little confusing because the debugger doesn't actually use them. Let me elaborate.

By default, you get three web.configs: `Web.config`, `Web.Debug.config` and `Web.Release.config`. The latter two, are combined with the first in the Solution Explorer, but you can expand `Web.config` to see them. `Web.Debug.config` and `Web.Release.config` are the transforms. They use a special XML-style syntax to allow you alter, or *transform*, settings in the main `Web.config` file. Each corresponds to a "Configuration", namely "Debug" and "Release", the two built into Visual Studio by default. You can add additional configurations as you need them.

Now, here's where things are confusing. The `Debug` configuration, despite its name, is never actually used when debugging. A better name would be perhaps `Development` or `Staging`; it's the configuration intended for when you deploy the site in a testing capacity, rather than to production. The `Release` config is for production. So, what you need is in your main `Web.config`, specify the connection string for your local development database. Then, in the `Debug` and `Release` configs, you add a transform to change that to the staging/production database connection strings, respectively. When you're debugging locally, the one the main `web.config` will be used, and then when you publish your application, you'll choose to either use `Debug` or `Release`, based on the environment you'll be deploying to, and *then* the transforms will be run to alter the published `web.config` appropriately.

For more information on transforms and how to write them, see: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Provide your connection name or connection string to the DbContext constructor.

```
public class YourContext : DbContext {

    public YourContext(string connection) : base(connection)
    {
    }

}
```

The string can be a variable your application modifies based on what database you want to connect to.

**EDIT:** updated the example so that now you have a constructor that accepts a string parameter which then passes it to the base class when instantiated.

Comment: Thanks, but how does one change the name that is setup to this method in the .Context.cs class?  Basically, I don't know how to change "yourNameOrConnectionString" to "MyDBProd" or "MyDBTest" programmatically.

Comment: Another way to put this question: how to I instantiate the context using different connection strings from Web.config.  This is where I run into a problem: using (var db = new MyContext("MyDBTest"))  My assumption was that I would be able to enter the name of any connection string here, but this doesn't work.  I get an error stating that there is no constructor for the context that accepts 1 argument.  I don't understand how I can pass an argument to this constructor and have it go to the base() class (as in your example).  How do I replace "yourNameOrConnectionString" with a var from my call?

Comment: updated the example so that you can pass an argument to your derived context class.